# Android: Getting into right condition using fileinputstream

Tags: android, if-statement, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I'm facing a different problem, see below is the code for my app that can read stored file and have to check condition according to that.

My inputs are "ON" and "OFF"

```
String val="";
final ToggleButton start = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.startup);
        FileInputStream fileos;
        try {
            fileos = openFileInput("startup");
            byte[] input = new byte[fileos.available()];
            while(fileos.read(input) != -1){
                val += new String(input);
            }
            if(val.toString() == "ON"){
                start.setChecked(true);
            }else if(val.toString() == "OFF"){
                start.setChecked(false);
            }else{
                start.setChecked(true);
            }
            fileos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

The above code fetching the output correctly either "ON" or "OFF", But it Always going into else conditionelse

```
else{ start.setChecked(true); }
```

I'm stucked here, Please help me some one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to compare the string using .equals()

```
if(val.equals("ON")){
      start.setChecked(true);
}else if(val.equals("OFF")){
     start.setChecked(false);
}else{
    start.setChecked(true);
}
```

Comment: to keep it short in this case this would be enoguh:

if(val.equals("OFF")){
     start.setChecked(false);
}else{
    start.setChecked(true);
}

Comment: If we were looking for short, you could go with `start.setChecked(value.equals("ON"))`.

Comment: You're very helped me Dodge :) Thanks for the help.I'm new to android and java. Basically I'm a php developer so i checked condition like that. So now i realized because of you. Thank you soooo much :)))

Answer (score 1):

android is based in java , in java you can't use "==" to compare two strings , you should replace

```
val.toString() == "ON"
```

to

```
"ON".equals(val.toString())
```

Comment: Thank you :) Dodged helped me out with the same. Its working fine now

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two big problems with this code. One is that you must use the `equals()` method to compare `String` objects, *always* -- the `==` operator is appropriate only in very limited cases.

The second one is more subtle, and won't break all the time. When you read data into `input`, although you're using a loop, the code will only work if all the data is read at once. This is because you're creating a `String` out of the entire array, even if the entire array doesn't contain valid data. The correct loop would look like this:

```
int count;
while((count = fileos.read(input)) != -1){
    val += new String(input, 0, count);
}
```

Comment: No problem with while Ernest Friedman-Hill. Thank you so much for your time. :)

Comment: What on Earth do you mean, "no problem with `while`?" The code is wrong. Doesn't matter if it seems to work most of the time -- wrong is wrong. This is a terrible attitude, son.

Comment: Apology for my attitude sir, Honestly speaking I'm new to android and java as well. So i don't knew it. Thank you. I'd try it :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.equals()` to compare `String`s. Do no use ==

```
val.toString().equals("ON")
```